Baseband downconversion without imaging
I am a high school intern at a company employing heavy DSP and trying to learn the basics from the ground up. One feature of a test application I'm creating is the ability to zoom an FFT graph and gain increased resolution. I am following this guide which has been helpful, but I have run into a wall.
The first step in the process of applying a zoom FFT, as I understand it, is to downmix my passband signal to baseband, using the lower bound of the zoom range as the center frequency. This places the desired portion of the graph in the baseband, which can then be low-pass filtered and decimated for increased FFT resolution. However, I am running into problems with imaging. I am noticing that graph components in the theoretical "negative frequency" range of the graph are causing undesirable artifacts in my FFT. I have a conceptual understanding of why this takes place due to a number of helpful graphs.
The article I am following, as I understand it, claims to have a solution that eliminates these artifacts using Euler's identity. I do not totally understand it, but I see that it relates to the even and odd behavior of the cosine and sine functions. I thought that I correctly implemented this in my code. This is a snippet of my code, assuming payload is an array of [real, complex, real, complex, ...]:
// filter: freq shift passband to baseband
for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i += 2) {
  let real = payload[i],
    imag = payload[i+1],
    k = i / 2;  // sample n

  payload[i] = (real * Math.cos(arg * k)) + (imag * Math.sin(arg * k));  // reals
  payload[i+1] = (imag * Math.cos(arg * k)) - (real * Math.sin(arg * k));  // imags
}

However, when tested with a sample wave consisting of two peaks, predicted undesirable artifacts are still present. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can fix my filter to obtain the correct spectrum at baseband.
EDIT: After some reading, I devised that given a sample with a real and imaginary part, this is the manipulation I need to perform to multiply by a complex sinusoid:
Sample = x = [r,i]
Local oscillator = cos(...) + isin(...)

Multiply both components by oscillator:

  x[r] * (cos(...) + isin(...))

 x[i]i * (cos(...) + isin(...))
= x[i] * (cos(...) - isin(...))

However, implementing this in code yields the same result as the snippet I had before. Thoughts?
EDIT 5/22: After implementing @AHT's comment, here's what my algorithm currently looks like:
// filter: freq shift passband to baseband
for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i += 2) {
  let real = payload[i],
    imag = payload[i+1],
    k = i / 2;  // sample n

  let cr = Math.cos(arg * k);
  let ci = -Math.sin(arg * k);
  
  // complex multiplication of sample and carrier
  payload[i] = real * cr - imag * ci;  // real
  payload[i+1] = real * ci + imag * cr;  // imag
}

However, when executed in the graph, images from negative frequencies still appear. Here's some images to better represent the issue.
NOTE: When the graph is "zoomed", the axes are programmed to change, but for the purpose of this visual, simply imagine it as a shift to baseband.

Figure 1: the original sample spectrum, sampled at 1 mHz



Intermediate step: graph is zoomed on the interval 275 kHz - 500 khZ

Figure 2: the graph after a baseband downconvert centered at 275 kHz (first step in the zoom FFT)



While the peak at 350 kHz is correctly centered because it was within zoom bounds, the peak at 250 kHz (or, better interpreted as -250 kHz) pollutes the spectrum at 300 kHz (which can be understood as 25hz of the equivalent baseband graph with no axes).

Note that there is a common misconception that the zoom fft can increase frequency resolution. It cannot. What it does is reduce complexity and achieve the same frequency resolution you would get from a full FFT. That might be of interest for some application where complexity is an issue of course, but that’s a question you need to ask yourself before falling into the zoom fft trap!

@Jdip Yes, I understand this. By increased resolution I meant the same resolution but of a small subset of the graph.

ok. But again, if you don't have processing restrictions, there's no point doing a zoom fft. (unless your bandwidth of interest is a very small subset of the full bandwidth).
You can just do a full fft and get the same info you would get from a zoom fft

@Jdip My application is intended to support zooming to a decent resolution for sample rates that could approach gigahertz. I think the zoom FFT will be necessary given the requirement for relatively high sample rates.

Ok! You seem to not be falling in an unnecessary trap then ;)

Note that multiplying two complex numbers: the $n$th signal sample $x[n]=x_r[n]+ix_i[n]$ and the $n$th sample of the carrier $c[n]=c_r[n]+ic_i[n]$ results in $y[n]=y_r[n]+iy_i[n]=\left(x_r[n]*c_r[n]-x_i[n]*c_i[n]\right)+i\left(x_r[n]*c_i[n]+x_i[n]*c_r[n]\right)$, i.e, $y_r[n]=x_r[n]*c_r[n]-x_i[n]*c_i[n]$ and $y_i[n]=x_r[n]*c_i[n]+x_i[n]*c_r[n]$.

@AHT Thank you writing this out, but reorganizing some terms shows that this is basically equivalent to the original method, and the problem persists. I made some edits to better demonstrate the issue.

@moltarze Please see the reply in the Answer below.

@moltarze Still you did not implement down conversion correctly, I think.
Let $x[n] = x_r[n] + ix_i[n]$ be the input signal to be down-converted by the carrier
$$c[n] = e^{-in\text{arg}} = \cos(n\times\text{arg}) - i\sin(n\times\text{arg})$$
Then the down-converted signal
\begin{eqnarray}
y[n] & = & y_r[n] + iy_i[n] \\
& = & \underbrace{\left(x_r[n]\cos(n\times\text{arg})+x_i[n]\sin(n\times\text{arg})\right)}_{y_r[n]} \\
& + & i\underbrace{\left(-x_r[n]\sin(n\times\text{arg})+x_i[n]\cos(n\times\text{arg})\right)}_{y_i[n]}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, you may want to modify your code as
payload[i] = real * cr + imag * ci; // real (y_r[n])
payload[i+1] = -real * ci + imag * cr; // imag (y_i[n])


Thank you for the help, this worked perfectly.

Keep in mind that multiplying an input time-domain signal by a cosine wave (or a sine wave) is "modulation" and NOT "frequency translation." To implement frequency translation you must multiplying an input time-domain signal by a complex sinusoid (cos()+jsin()). Here is material from the book "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" that may help you better understand the Zoom FFT process:
https://www.embedded.com/using-zoom-fft-for-spectral-analysis/

Hello - was my method not utilizing a complex sinusoid? I was pretty sure that my code followed the complex multiplication method set forth in the article.
